# "Operation not permitted" running hello world binary compiled w/ clang++ on El Capitan

Tags: c++, osx-elcapitan, clang++

**Background**

I created a simple Hello World C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And compiled it with clang++ like so (g++ points to clang++ on OS X apparently):

```
g++ helloworld-cpp.cpp
```

This produces an executable, `a.out`.  Running it at the prompt causes bash to throw the error `Operation not permitted`, as shown:

```
$ ./a.out
-bash: ./a.out: Operation not permitted
```

**Things I've Tried**

1. Verifying the file has execute permissions, and no attributes or flags that would prevent it from running, using `ls -leO`:

   `-rwxr-xr-x  1 monarch  staff  - 15212 Jan  1 13:51 a.out`
2. Disabling "System Integrity Protection" using `csrutil disable` from the Recovery OS terminal, rebooting, recompiling, and running `a.out`.  The same error messages results.

**Question**

Are there any other restrictions that could prevent binaries I compile on Mac OS X from running?

Comment: "Operation not permitted" is likely related to something like a shared library not being avialble.  [And g++ points to clang++, not llvm, although indeed, clang does use llvm to produce the machine code - I know, details, but still correct details]

Comment: `sudo chmod u+x a.out`?

Comment: I would do `strace ./a.out` and see what that does.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: Uh, the result of `ls -l` shows that the file is executable for everyone...

Comment: Did you try first running `xcode-select --install` in a terminal? Although probably not the issue...

Comment: Does `otool -L ./a.out` show anything unexpected?  Are the libraries it lists all accessible?

Comment: @Mats Petersson It appears OS X doesn't come with `strace`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler results of otool: `/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib` and `/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib` both files are readable and executable by everyone.  I did notice that both have the restricted flag when using `ls -lO`, but I think this just means System Integrity Protection won't let you modify those files.

Comment: @vsoftco I did try that just in case, though presumably those were installed when I set up Xcode a while back (after El Capitan upgrade).  I needed them to set up homebrew.

Comment: Try actually compiling with `clang++` rather than what you think might be a link to it. Failing that, reinstall Xcode from AppStore and re-run `xcode-select --install` and recompile.

Comment: You aren't on a filesystem mounted with `noexec` are you?

Comment: I'm not sure.  On my Mac OS X 10.11.2 MacBook Pro, I'm able to compile and run the code with `clang++ -o hw hw.cpp; ./hw`.  Likewise when I use `/usr/bin/g++` (unqualified, `g++` is GCC 5.3.0 in a wholly different install area — that works too).  I get the `otool -L` output: `/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.1.0)` and
`/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)`.  Do you get different current versions, perchance?  Can you compile and run a C 'hello world' program? Do you have `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` set in the env?

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks, that let me to the answer!  The code was in a sparse image mounted with the `quarantined` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

My code was on an encrypted sparseimage, which had the `quarantined` attribute set on it.  I checked this by running `mount` like so (see attributes on `/Volumes/work`):

```
$ mount
/dev/disk0s2 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
/dev/disk2s2 on /Volumes/work (hfs, local, nodev, nosuid, journaled, noowners, quarantine, mounted by monarch)
```

The actual sparseimage is located in my home folder, titled `work.sparseimage`.  I removed the quarantine attribute like so:

```
$ xattr -d com.apple.quarantine work_personal.sparseimage
```

I then unmounted (ejected) the image, then re-mounted it, recompiled the file and it executed without the error.

*Special thanks to @Mark Setchell for asking me in the question's comments if `noexec` was set on the drive, and to everyone else for their suggestions.*